# Converting data stored as text to numbers (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, excel

I have some data that i pull from a couple of Oracle databases into Excel via a VBA macro. Some of the columns have data (numbers), afaik, stored as text. I need to convert these "wrongly" formatted data to numbers so that i can do calculations on it, however i cant figure out how to do this effectively using VBA. Furthermore only some of the data is stored as text (columns K-Q are formatted incorrectly, see picture below).

Currently im using this loop to convert the data:

```
Sub convertTextToNumbers(ByVal sColumnHeader As String)
    Dim col As Range, c As Range
    Dim colIndexNumber As Integer, lastUsedRow As Integer

    colIndexNumber = findColumnIndexNumber(sColumnHeader)

    lastUsedRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, colIndexNumber).End(xlUp).Row

    Set col = Range(Cells(2, colIndexNumber), Cells(lastUsedRow, colIndexNumber))

    For Each c In col
        c.Value = c.Value
    Next c
End Sub
```

Is this the most effective way to do it? Can i convert using SQL? The SQL-query im using is simply:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
```

Also converting by choosing another formatting does not work.

Thanks!

**Data wrongly formatted is in columns K-Q:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N93D8.png]

Comment: use the to_number sql function to convert the columns needed.

Comment: just wondering why don't you make an ODBC connection and use it in Excel?

Comment: What should the formats be in K - N?

Comment: **OldProgrammer** i think this is exactly what i need. I also found the to_date and to_timestamp functions  
**user206168** i am pulling the data from an ODBC connection, giving me the above  
**MatthewD** the formats in K - N and P - Q are supposed to be timestamps. If i do eg. =K10+K11 it will work, however =SUM(K10:K11) does not work.

Comment: You should be able to pull them as a timestamp with to_timestamp. Note if you use todate you may have to include the timestamp IE 2015-01-01 59:59:59. If not you can apply the timestamp to the cells using the number format.

Answer (score 1):

Use number format on the columns.

```
Columns("K:Q").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Or more programmatic

```
Private Sub formatNumbers()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
    ws.Range("K:Q").NumberFormat = "0.00"

End Sub
```

Any format you see in the range format menu can be applied this way.

[image]

Comment: Are you applying it before you write the value to the cell?

Comment: No it is applied afterwards